# Provider independent SIP address

Tags: sip

I'm currently investigating getting a (private) SIP account and have looked around various providers.

As far as I can see they all give you addresses like `myname@sip-provider.com` but if I would distribute that to friends and would want to switch providers later I would have to tell everyone that I can now be reached at `my.name@another-provider.com`.

This reminds me of the 90s where everyone had email addresses issued by their ISP and I don't want to repeat that. Basically I want a SIP address that I can transfer from one provider to another. I have an Ubuntu VPS and I'm wondering if I can some sort of redirect from my VPS to the actual SIP provider?

Answer (score 1):

You don't "redirect" VPSes, you redirect *domain names*. Like you would do with email -- except instead of `MX` records you set up `SRV`s. See [RFC 3263: Locating SIP Servers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3263).

Answer (score 1):

I think [ekiga.net](https://www.ekiga.net/) is what you're looking for, it provides provider agnostic SIP address that you can have your provider forward your calls to

Answer (score 0):

you can rent a VPS, install a PBX software (I personally prefer FreeSWITCH, but Asterisk would also do the job) and connect it to your SIP provider(s). You can use several SIP providers for different purposes or for cost savings.

Then in your own domain, you add SRV DNS records pointing to your own server.

As a side effect, you can add a new line to your CV :)